# How can I find out what user from a specified IP is doing with my server?

Tags: linux, intrusion-detection

Yesterday night around 2:00, I occasionally try out a snippet:

`netstat -ntu | tail -n +3|awk '{ print $5}' | cut -d : -f 1 | sort | uniq -c| sort -n -r | head -n 5`

Then it turns out one IP is having almost 120+ entries (I am not sure whether this word is appropriate)! The server where I ran the script above doesn't have much interesting stuff, just server with blogs which are almost never visited by people besides my friends. I think the phenomenon is really suspicious.

How can I find out what the user from the suspicious ip is doing? I don't any person who can have such a high interest in those blogs deep in the night. By the way, I checked the IP and found the ip is in my country, so it's not time-zone problem.

Comment: What service were they connecting to?

Comment: Sadly I forgot about that! Just now I can check the command again and the output is quite normal now.

Comment: You should always keep logs like this, and make sure to also keep a timestamp of when the log was created that is as exact as possible (with the time zone).

Comment: You are totally right. I just keep track of output of the script mentioned, but forget to record the result of netstat -ntu ...

Comment: Start with a `whois ${IP_Address}` and see what that returns, it's probably a webcrawler or script kiddie. Either way, really nothing to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the access logs of your web server to find out more.

If you are using Apache you can find them in the `/var/log/apache2` or `/var/log/httpd/` directory.

You probably shouldn't be too worried. It's probably just a search engine crawling your websites and blogs. They tend to be very thorough.

Comment: I search the blog log and all other website logs and grep show nothing...